# Can you figure out the password hashing scheme?

Tags: security, encryption, hash, passwords

I have two passwords and two resulting hashes. I can't figure out how the hash is derived from the password. I don't know if salting is used. I don't know if the password is hashed as a integer value or as a string (possibly Unicode).

Password: `6770` Hash: `c12114b91a3841c143bbeb121693e80b`

Password: `9591` Hash: `25238d578b6a61c2c54bfe55742984c1`

The hash length seems to suggest MD5. Anybody has any ideas what I could try?

Note: This is not for hacking purposes. I'm trying to access a service through an API instead of it's desktop client, and I can't figure out how to compute the password hash. Currently instead of using my real password I'm sending directly the hash.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Googling up those hash values (!) reveals that 25238d578b6a61c2c54bfe55742984c1 is the *md2sum* of "9591" ([source](http://rulus.com/tool/hash/959)), and that site has another page confirming the same for 6770 and your first hash value ([source2](http://rulus.com/tool/hash/677)).

(Edit: I have since googled up some md2 source code and cross-checked the hashes.)

*(Edited again to comment: You are incredibly lucky that this API uses such a terrible hashing scheme without any salting or prefixes! :-) )*

Answer (score 3):

The API documentation doesn't say? Strange.

In principle, this is an impossible problem - any number of different hash algorithms can give the same results in any given number of particular cases, and then give a different result the first time you rely on one.

In practice, though, you can probably just try a few common crypto hash algorithms and see what they give you. If one matches in a few randomly chosen cases, it's probably right. A malicious person might, e.g., remap a few characters (swap '2' for '3' or whatever - you wouldn't spot that with your example passwords) before applying the main hash algorithm, but it's unlikely in real apps.

BTW - a four-numeric-digit password is about as secure as not having a password at all.